# How to make a DataTable ReadOnly?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, sqlclient

I am writing a function that return a DataTable object. I am using the `DataTable.Load( DataReader)` to populate the DataTable.  However, as I understand it, although the underlying DataReader is ReadOnly, Forward-only; once it is loaded into the DataTable; other programmers can still update the data by `DataTable.Rows(x).Column(y).ReadOnly = False` and then setting the value.

Is there away to ensure that the DataTable that my function return is ReadOnly?
In the older ADODB days, I use the ADODB.LockTypeEnum to mark the returned recordset is readonly.

By ReadOnly, I mean that the caller to my function (who get the returned DataTable) cannot make changes to the Rows data and/or update it at all (ie, readonly).

Comment: For 'ReadOnly' do you mean how to block any update to the underlying database?

Comment: A DataTable, a DataView or a DataSet are `disconnected` objects on the ADO.NET world. You can change every single data in these objects, but this doesn't mean that you are writing directly to the database. These objectes are changed `in memory` not on disk. You need to explicitily write these changes back to the database using the appropriate connection and command objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there away to ensure that the DataTable that my function return is
>   ReadOnly?

No, generally there is no such method or way to make it readonly. Unlike the `DataView`which has the property [`AllowEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.allowedit.aspx) for this purpose( so you could return a DataView instead).

The only way i see to avoid changes on the table is: try to handle the [`RowChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and call [`RejectChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rejectchanges.aspx) afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the input Tim. I'll hold on for another day or 2 to see if there are alternatives. If not, then I'll mark yours as answer. Thanks.

Comment: But the caller can still alter the AllowEdit property.  So if you want to make sure nothing outside your function can possibly alter the contents of the DataTable, then this isn't much use.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to prevent a caller from corrupting your internal DataTable (or DataSet) is to return a copy.  Both the DataSet and DataTable classes have a Copy() method that duplicates both the structure and data of the original.

Obviously, this will work better with DataTables containing relatively small amounts of data.